# Download a dataframe as csv in Flex Dashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a flex dashboard that is designed to share as a stand alone html file. What I would like to do is allow my reader to download some of the raw data sets used in the report. I can't use a shiny download button because it won't work in static html file.

I had a variety of thoughts on this:

```
  palette <- monkeyr::get_heat_palette(6)

  myData <- data.frame(
    Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
    Age = c(25, 30, 22)
  )

  flexdashboard::valueBox(paste0("Device Data"),
                          icon = "fa-tablet",
                          href = paste0(write.csv(myData, row.names = FALSE)),
                          # color = ifelse(below_18 > 0.40, "warning", "primary"),
                          color = palette[6])
```

Obviously doesn't work, but is there a way to modify the href so it will?

This works:

```
<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BFYOUR_CSV_DATA_HERE" download="my_data.csv">
```

But all my efforts to replace the fixed text with the contents of the csv have failed:

```
<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF <%= paste0(csv_content) %> " download="my_data.csv">
  Download CSV File
</a>
```

**One last ditch try!** Now I'm genuinely perplexed as to why this doesn't work. It one of the ugliest pieces of code I've ever written, but why is the paste0 function not doing what I expect?

```
  myData <- data.frame(
    Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
    Age = c(25, 30, 22)  
  )

  link1 <- paste0('<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF', write.csv(myData, row.names = FALSE), '" download="my_data.csv">')
  link2 <- "  Download My CSV"
  link3 <- "</a>"
```

I then print these out. The link code works fine, but the contect isn't there!

If I assign the value to link1 and print it out, I see this:

```
> link1
[1] "<a href=\"data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF\" download=\"my_data.csv\">"
```

Where has the csv content gone???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

- use the DT package, which allows to display a dataframe and to download it as CSV (or even XLSX)
- use the [downloadthis package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/downloadthis/vignettes/downloadthis.html)

Comment: I've tried everything under the sun to get your first option to work to no avail. Would you mind sharing a working example? if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: Actually, scratch that. Your second reference works like a charm. How did I not know about that package?!